# Install sample data using Composer - Command prompt hangs when asked for password

Tags: magento2, composer

I'm trying to install Magento2 using composer but when i'm prompted to add my private key the command prompt hangs, not letting me enter my private key.

[image]

Comment: Can you comment specific version here?

Comment: Oh also, when I have having these issues (OSX) it was ssl related.  You should make sure what ssl version your windows machine is actively using here for the repository.

Answer (score 0):

you copy and paste your private key into the command prompt. You can't see the private key you pasted in, but if you press enter and wait it should work.